# How to create a React code to display the input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help to insert number and display the number somewhere, I have install Babel and react and it is very confusing to understand.

Code for my input:

```
React.createElement("div", { className: "ad-Controls-container" },
    React.createElement(Control, {
        name: "millimeter",
        type: "text",
        value: props.mm,
        onChange: e => props.setMillimeter(e) })),
```

Code for my output:

```
React.createElement("textarea", {
        className: "ad-Result-textarea",
        value: props.mm,
        //onFocus: e => props.mm(e)})
        onChange: e => props.setMillimeter(e)})
```

Comment: Are you deliberately not using JSX? If you're new to React, try learning JSX and use `create-react-app` to get you started.

Comment: hmm i try first

Comment: To add to that, if you're new to React: [the official React tutorial exists for a very good reason](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). Take it. Spend the 15-30 minutes up front so you actually understand how React works, and are at least passingly familiar with its conventions, before you start inventing your own React code.